# Find files whose name contains "AC" and the list of file whose name starts with "RES"

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have more than 500 files whose names starts with `RES` and some of the files which has 2 middle character as `AC`.

For example I have list of files like this where some files starts with `RES` and 5th and 6th character are `AC` and I want to list out those file with those matches.

```
RESLSJFKLS 
RESLJKGJFI
SCKJACFKJE
RESLJLJAAK
NCIEACKLUS
RESLJVLISS
LKJOJGOIOU
JOIUOUGOLJ
SEUOGJSLKJ
RESBKJOWES
```

Comment: Which of the filenames in your example do you want in the output?

Comment: Does your file has no extension?

Comment: Can just ls into grep.

Comment: 'has 2 middle character as AC' _or_ ' 5th and 6th character are AC'.

Comment: `ls | egrep 'RES|AC'` or `ls | egrep 'RES|AC' | cat -n`

Comment: with custom color green: `perl -le 's/RES|AC/\033[1;32m$&\033[m/g && print ++$n,": ",$_ for <*>'`

Comment: **None of your inputs has `AC` after `RES` so your question is not clear enough**

Answer (score 0):

**Using ls**

If the files are in one directory with no subdirectories use

```
#> ls -1 RES?AC*
```

**Using find**

General option covering directory trees

```
#> find ./ -name 'RES?AC*'
```

Comment: The condition is an `and` or is an `or`. I mean; The name begins with RES and has AC in the 5th, 6th position or can be any of those conditions?. Also... Are you trying only in those examples or are trying on your actual directory with the 500 or so files ?

Comment: My bad... Forgot to include the `*`

Comment: I want to separate out the file begin with "RES" and the file has 5th and 6th character as "AC". 
I'm trying on my actual directory.

Comment: Expression now has a trailing `*`. Give it a try.

Comment: $ls -l RES?AC *  -- i tried this one and give me all files regardless of the search pattern.

Comment: There is a space between `C` and `*`. remove it. And is an `1` (number one) not an `l` (letter l)

Comment: if i remove space between C and * it gives me error " ls: RES?AC*: No such file or directory "

Comment: Can you supply in your post a filename, or many, that will match the search ?

Comment: I can't copy all files from my work machines, the files above i posted in post i typed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Shells do not uses regular expressions for argument expansion.

You can enable the extended pattern matching by

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

and then try this,

```
 ls @(RES*|????AC*)
```

The above matches the files that begin with  'RES' and the files that have fifth and sixth character as 'AC'. Works good . hope it helps.

See for example  [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: Its not working.. I got error "ls: @(RES *|???? AC *): No such file or directory" "

Comment: I have checked with the same file names that you have posted, It worked for me. The files that gave me output as "RESLSJFKLS 
RESLJKGJFI
SCKJACFKJE
RESLJLJAAK
NCIEACKLUS
RESLJVLISS"

Comment: Else you edit post with the output you required.That would clearly understand me to try more

Comment: @Jay Did you have spaces inbetween ? AC *)